# My Trigger wont work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I have been working on a trigger for my SQL database.

**The tables:**

TABLE1: ID(int, auto increment), value1(varchar), value2(varchar), count(int)

TABLE1_History: ID(Separate from TABLE1.ID, int, auto increment), same columns as TABLE1 but with an added TimeStamp(smalldatetime)

**The code:**

```
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT FROM TABLE1_History, INSERTED
    WHERE TABLE1_History.value1 LIKE INSERTED.value1
    AND TABLE1_History.value2 LIKE INSERTED.value2
    AND DATEDIFF(HOUR,TABLE1_History."TimeStamp", GETDATE()) > 24;

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TABLE1_History(value1, value2, count, "TimeStamp")
        SELECT value1, value2, count, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TABLE1_History
        SET "TimeStamp" = GETDATE(), count = count+(SELECT count FROM INSERTED)
        WHERE TABLE1_History.value1 LIKE (SELECT value1 FROM INSERTED)
        AND TABLE1_History.value2 LIKE (SELECT value2 FROM INSERTED)
        AND DATEDIFF(HOUR,TABLE1_History."TimeStamp", GETDATE()) < 24;
    END
END
```

**What's supposed to happen:**

When I Add a new row to TABLE1 I want TABLE1_History to update.

TABLE1_History *ONLY* adds new rows if a row already exists with the same value1&value2 as the new row *AND* if it's been more than 24hours since that row was added.

Otherwise, the counter increases.

**What happens:**

As of now: TABLE1_History gets updated every time. Doesn't matter if the values match or not.

It seemed to work before I decided to let TABLE1_History.ID be separate from TABLE1.ID.

Comment: SQL-Server? Please add the tag.

Comment: you mean tag in stackoverflow? in that case, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should avoid using keywords so `TimeStamp`. if you can change it to `LastModified` or something

dont use `@@ROWCOUNT`, you could join `INSERTED`, and i'm not sure why you are using `LIKE`. Try this

```
IF NOT( EXISTS (   -- if it's not already in the table
    SELECT value1 FROM TABLE1_History
    JOIN INSERTED ON TABLE1_History.value1 = INSERTED.value1
                 AND TABLE1_History.value2 = INSERTED.value2
   ) )
   OR EXISTS (    -- or its history was last modified over 24 hours ago
    SELECT value1 FROM TABLE1_History
    JOIN INSERTED ON TABLE1_History.value1 = INSERTED.value1
                 AND TABLE1_History.value2 = INSERTED.value2
                 AND DATEDIFF(HOUR,TABLE1_History."TimeStamp", GETDATE()) > 24
   )       
BEGIN             -- insert it into the history table
    INSERT INTO TABLE1_History(value1, value2, count, "TimeStamp")
    SELECT value1, value2, count, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED
END
ELSE
BEGIN             -- otherwise update the current history record
    UPDATE th
    SET th."TimeStamp" = GETDATE()
        , th.count = th.count + INSERTED.count
    FROM TABLE1_History th
    JOIN INSERTED ON th.value1 = INSERTED.value1
                 AND th.value2 = INSERTED.value2
                 AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, th."TimeStamp", GETDATE()) < 24;
END
```

Comment: Probably better than my solution. Your trigger works for when the values are the same. But when they are differe from each other, nothig happens.

Comment: I tried emptying the tables now and realized that Nothing gets added in History now

Comment: @Yoan have fixed to allow 'new' records